# Populate Viewmodel inside an IF statement?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, if-statement

Im trying to populate a viewmodel based on the value from the querystring. Heres my controller:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? ShiftStatusID)
{
    //Get logged in User
    User user = _accountService.GetUser(_formsAuthService.GetLoggedInUserID());

    if (ShiftStatusID == null) // Get all shifts
    {
        ViewModelShiftList viewModel = new ViewModelShiftList
        {
            Shifts = _shiftService.GetShifts(user.organisationID.Value).ToList()
        };
    }
    else // Get shifts by status id
    {
        ViewModelShiftList viewModel = new ViewModelShiftList
        {
            Shifts = _shiftService.GetShiftsByStatus(user.organisationID.Value, ShiftStatusID).ToList()  
        };
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

So it wont let me return the viewmodel to the view, saying "viewmodel does not exist in the current context". It wont let me declare the view model outside the if statement. How should this be done?

Comment: SORTED: I needed to return the viewmodel within the if statement

Comment: Take your viewmodel declaration out of if statement. By default your code should return a declared viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move out if statement in your viewresult.
Here is a code example which should be working fine:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? ShiftStatusID)
{
       //Get logged in User
        User user = _accountService.GetUser(_formsAuthService.GetLoggedInUserID());
        var viewModel = new ViewModelShiftList();

        if (ShiftStatusID.HasValue)// Get shifts by status id
        {
            viewModel.Shifts = _shiftService.GetShifts(user.organisationID.Value).ToList();
        }
        else // Get all shifts
        {
            viewModel.Shifts = _shiftService.GetShiftsByStatus(user.organisationID.Value, ShiftStatusID).ToList();
        }

    return View(viewModel);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I seen where I was going wrong, thanks for the extra tips

Answer (score 0):

Clean up your code, remove duplicate lines:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? ShiftStatusID)
{
    //Get logged in User
    User user = _accountService.GetUser(_formsAuthService.GetLoggedInUserID());

    List<Shift> shifts;

    if(ShiftStatusID == null)
        shifts = _shiftService.GetShifts(user.organisationID.Value).ToList();
    else
        shifts = _shiftService.GetShiftsByStatus(user.organisationID.Value, ShiftStatusID).ToList();

    var viewModel = new ViewModelShiftList
    {
        Shifts = shifts
    };

    return View(viewModel);
}
```